# Determine if a number is divisible by 3 without using mathematical operators

Tags: c, recursion

I got this assignment as homework and I can't figure out how to do it:

> Input is a string of the numbers 1, 2 and 3.
>   You need to build a function that determines if the number represented by the string is divisible by 3.
>
> **Rules:**
>
> - No loops.
> - No math operations (+,-,*,/,%) on the number.
> - Use recursion.
>
> **Hint:** if the sum of the digits of a number is divisible by 3 - so is the number.

I tried using the hint to come up with an algorithm to do this, but it does not work (if 1 and 2 appear an equal number of times, then the number is divisible by 3. But then if the number is composed of only 1 or 2 it can still be divisible, and we found ourselves again with the same problem).

Any ideas?

Comment: The constraints here are so arbitrary I think we need to see the effort you've made so far. Would you mind pasting up the relevant parts? I'm not sure how you can sum the digits in the number without using `+`.

Comment: You're allowed to use mathematical operations on the individual digits and their sum, so just sum them and `%` them.

Comment: Another "write mostly obfuscated code" assignment. Your teacher would not survive one week as a professional programmer.

Comment: Please don't downvote this on the grounds that the assignment is dodgy.

Comment: Agree that from an educational viewpoint this assignment is really not very useful. From any other viewpoint, as well.

Answer (score 3):

Well, how silly can you go? The entry point is `divBy3_0`, just call it with the string.

```
bool divBy3_0(char const *n);
bool divBy3_1(char const *n);
bool divBy3_2(char const *n);

bool divBy3_0(char const *n) {
    switch(*n) {
        case '1': return divBy3_1(&n[1]);
        case '2': return divBy3_2(&n[1]);
        case '3': return divBy3_0(&n[1]);
    }

    return true;
}

bool divBy3_1(char const *n) {
    switch(*n) {
        case '1': return divBy3_2(&n[1]);
        case '2': return divBy3_0(&n[1]);
        case '3': return divBy3_1(&n[1]);
    }

    return false;
}

bool divBy3_2(char const *n) {
    switch(*n) {
        case '1': return divBy3_0(&n[1]);
        case '2': return divBy3_1(&n[1]);
        case '3': return divBy3_2(&n[1]);
    }

    return false;
}
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f29c8424e8610712)

Comment: `++n` is an addition.

Comment: @Olaf barely. Would `&n[1]` soothe you ? ;)

Comment: No. Neither would `&1[n]` (valid!) be acceptable. Read the standard how the index-operator is defined.

Comment: @Olaf the restriction on operations is apparently at the source level. Otherwise we can note that calling the function performs an addition to the stack pointer, and thus the question cannot be solved at all.

Comment: I don't read this from the question text. Wrt the question "mathematical operators", `[]` **is** a mathematical operator (actually it is also factually.

Comment: @Olaf "math operations" are defined in the question as "(+,-,*,/,%)". Bitwise operators, boolean operators and square brackets are open for grabs (as are increments and decrements, but I found it funny so...)

Comment: @Olaf Perfect example of someone who thinks too literally. You need to understand the point of the question. With your argument it would be impossible to solve such a problem so that clearly isn't what is meant by the problem statement.

Comment: @Blued00d: Thank you for explaining it. As you seem to be the one who made the assignment (only that one can know how it is meant) you should help your student directly and maybe reconsider your didactics.

Comment: "how silly can you go" <-- I upvoted because of this quote.

Answer (score 2):

Based on recursion and binary addition (without `+-/*%`)

1. recursively sum digits in input (`sum_str_digits`)
2. check is it dividable by 3 (`is_dividable_by_3`):

   - if number equals to 3 or 6 or 9 return 1 (true)
   - if number equals to 2,4,5,7,8 or 0 return 0 (false)
   - otherwise go to 1) with sum

Sample code, of course it needs care (error handling especially)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int badd(int n1, int n2){
    int carry, sum;
    carry = (n1 & n2) << 1;
    sum = n1 ^ n2;
    if (sum & carry)
        return badd(sum, carry);
    else
        return sum ^ carry;
}

char * int_to_str(int n) {
    //int length_0 = snprintf( NULL, 0, "%d", n) + 1;
    int length_0 = 32;
    char* str = malloc(length_0);
    snprintf( str, length_0, "%d", n);
    return str;
}

int digit_to_int(char d) {
    char str[2];

    str[0] = d;
    str[1] = '\0';
    return (int) strtol(str, NULL, 10);
}

int sum_str_digits(char * s, int sum){
    sum = badd(sum, digit_to_int(s[0])); 
    if (s[1] == '\0') {
        printf("Sum: %d \n", sum);
        return sum; 
    }
    return sum_str_digits(&(s[1]), sum);;
}

int is_dividable_by_3(int n) {
    switch (n) {
        case 3:
        case 6:
        case 9:
            return 1;
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 0:
            return 0;
        default: {
            char * str = int_to_str(n);
            int x = sum_str_digits(str, 0);
            free(str);
            return is_dividable_by_3(x);
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int sum;
    sum = sum_str_digits(argv[1], 0);
    printf("Is div by 3: %d \n", is_dividable_by_3(sum));

    return 0;
}
```

Post edited - **previous version**

Recursive subtracting 3 in binary mode (without use of any math operator that are forbidden) until it equals three or less:

```
int badd(int n1, int n2){
    int carry, sum;
    carry = (n1 & n2) << 1; // Find bits that are used for carry
    sum = n1 ^ n2; // Add each bit, discard carry.
    if (sum & carry) // If bits match, add current sum and carry.
        return badd(sum, carry);
    else
        return sum ^ carry; // Return the sum.
}

int bsub(int n1, int n2){
    // Add two's complement and return.
    return badd(n1, badd(~n2, 1));
}
int idiv3(int n) {
    if (n == 3) {
       return 1;
    }
    if (n < 3) {
       return 0;
    }
    if (n > 3) {
        return idiv3(bsub(n, 3));
    }
}

int div3(const char *n) {
   return idiv3(strtol(n, (char **) NULL, 10));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This one should work. It replaces continuously subtracting 3 from the number by starting a loop from 3 up to the number, keeping a loop counter and recursively calling itself. `count++` **does use** some "+" character, but not the "+" operator and not on the number:

```
int f(int num){
   int count = 0, i;
   if(num == 3){
      puts ("number is divisible by 3");
   }
   else if(num < 3){
      puts ("number is not divisible");
   }
   else{
      for (i = 3; i < num; i++){
         count++;
      }
      num = count;
      f (num);
   }
}

void g (char *s) {
   f (atoi (s));
}
```

A typical "write a program without writing a program" assignment. I'm a bit afraid you really cannot learn much with regards to *practical* programming from this. (Other than how to waste computing resources with silly programs that are only allowed to use a subset of the language.)

Comment: Input is a string of digits, not an integer.

Comment: Thanks missed it. Trivial, but added.

Comment: Wouldn't you categorize `for` as a loop?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a modulo opperation on the `sum` is allowed, as long as the sum built using recursion. It could look as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int isDividableBy3_recursive(const char* n, int sum) {

    if (!n || !*n) {
        return (sum % 3 == 0) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    else {
        return isDividableBy3_recursive(n+1, sum+(*n - '0'));
    }
}


int isDividableBy3(const char* n) {

    return isDividableBy3_recursive(n,0);
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char* testNumbers[] = { "100", "233", "345", "3", "", NULL };

    for (int i=0;testNumbers[i]!=NULL;i++) {
        char* testNumber = testNumbers[i];
        printf("%s dividable by 3:%d\n", testNumber, isDividableBy3(testNumber));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i++` is an addition.

Comment: The `i++` is in the code testing the function; it should not matter as it is not part of the algorithm; Anyway, `+` etc is only forbidden when applied to the number.

Comment: `sum+(*n - '0')` is also testing code? And OP does not mention it was allowed anywhere. "is only forbidden when applied to the number" - the question text does not provide enough information to make such assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that pretty much everything done by a computer is a mathematical operation. So I submit one that the compiler ought to optimise to a jump table. Here's the "Olafesque-compliant" solution.

```
switch (the_damn_number)
{
    case 0:
        return true;
    case 1: case 2:
        return false;
    case 3:
        return true;
        // and so on
    case largest_number_I_care_about:
       // ToDo
}
```

(Use an `if` block if you're not allowed to convert the string to a `switch`able type.)

Use your favourite scripting tool to generate the code for you.

Comment: Can't beat this operator-free heaven of a function. Your Olaf Seal Of Approval™ will arrive shortly.

Comment: Wait, the assignment said "Use recursion", but there's no recursion here. I'm afraid that's grounds for disqualification...

Comment: I like the solution, even if it doesn't use recursion and is so somehow disqualified. But the professor should be forced to write out the complete case statements manually...

Answer (score -1):

Here's how you do it.

Your first job is to use `unsigned long long int strtoull(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);` to convert the string to an `unsigned long long`. Then apply that to

```
bool is_divisible_by_3(unsigned long long n)
{
    if (n > 9){
        // more than one digit
        return is_divisible_by_3(sum_digits_in_number(n));
    } else {
         return n == 0 || n == 3 || n == 6 || n == 9;
    }
}
```

You need to build `sum_digits_in_number(unsigned long long)`: it's difficult to see how you could do that without using `+`, `/`, or `%`, here's one way otherwise:

```
sum = 0;
while (n) {
    sum += n % 10;
    n /= 10;
}
```

Comment: Mmh... "Input is a string of the numbers 1, 2 and 3" :)

Comment: @Quentin: honestly you really have to spoon feed these days ;-)

Comment: Now that's funny: @Downvoter highlighted me... Not my DV though ;)

Comment: Comparison is a subtraction.

Comment: But do feel free to DV! It's that the system is for. @Olaf, what do you mean?

Comment: `n > 9` is a subtraction actually.

Comment: @Olaf, do enlighten me?

Comment: @Bathsheba: The comparision is performed by a subtraction. Not sure how more clear I can be.

Comment: @Olaf: I think that's merely conjecture. I could build a standards compliant C interpreter that doesn't use subtraction to evaluate `n > 9`.

Comment: @Bathsheba: But hardly without other mathematical operations. (not to mention the CPU's PC incrementing;-).